# Ruby - Get request body from incoming http call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am receiving http requests to my rails application to a url /account/postback

The body of this incoming request contains some json that I need to retrieve, how can I do this in ruby?

Answer (score 69):

The following should print the body of the request

routes.rb

```
map.connect 'account/:action', :controller => 'accounts'
```

accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def postback
    puts request.body.read    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

If your HTTP call is using the POST verb you could alternatively use `request.raw_post` to retrieve the contents sent in the request's body.

Hope it helps!